# Combination of approx and map2 is surprisingly slow

Tags: r, performance, data.table, purrr, linear-interpolation

I have a dataset that looks like the below:

```
> head(mydata)
   id value1 value2
1:  1 200001 300001
2:  2 200002 300002
3:  3 200003 300003
4:  4 200004 300004
5:  5 200005 300005
6:  6 200006 300006
```

`value1` and `value2` represent amounts at the beginning and the end of a given year. I would like to linearly interpolate the value for a given month, for each id (i.e. rowwise).

After trying different options that were slower, I am currently using `map2` from the `purrr` package in combination with `approx` from base R. I create the new variable using assignment by reference from the `data.table` package. This is still surprisingly slow, as it takes approximately 2.2 min for my code to run on my data (1.7 million rows).

Note that I also use `get()` to access the variables for the interpolation, as their names need to be dynamic. This is slowing down my code, but it doesn't seem to be the bottleneck. Also, I have tried to use the `furrr` package to speed up `map2` by making the code parallel, but the speed gains were not material.

Below is reproducible example with 1000 rows of data. Any help to speed up the code is greatly appreciated!

```
mydata <- data.table(id = 1:1000, value1= 2001:3000, value2= 3001:4000)
floor_value <- "value1"
ceiling_value <- "value2"
m <- 7

monthly_sum_assured <- function(a, b, m) {
  monthly_value <- approx(x = c(0, 12), c(a, b), xout = m)$y
}

mydata[, interpolated_value := map2(get(floor_value), get(ceiling_value),
                                    ~ monthly_sum_assured(.x, .y, m))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [the formula for linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Linear_interpolation_between_two_known_points) to vectorize over the whole `data.table`.

```
mydata <- data.table(id = 0:1e6, value1= 2e6:3e6, value2= 3e6:4e6)
floor_value <- "value1"
ceiling_value <- "value2"
m <- 7

monthly_sum_assured <- function(a, b, m) {
  monthly_value <- approx(x = c(0, 12), c(a, b), xout = m)$y
}

system.time({
  mydata[, interpolated_value := map2(get(floor_value), get(ceiling_value),
                                      ~ monthly_sum_assured(.x, .y, m))]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   41.50    0.53   42.05

system.time({
  mydata[, interpolated_value2 := get(floor_value) + m*(get(ceiling_value) - get(floor_value))/12]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0

identical(unlist(mydata$interpolated_value), mydata$interpolated_value2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

It also works just as fast when `m` is a vector.

```
m <- sample(12, 1e6 + 1, 1)
system.time({
  mydata[, interpolated_value2 := get(floor_value) + m*(get(ceiling_value) - get(floor_value))/12]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.01    0.00    0.02
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: If `floor_value` and/or `ceiling_value` are character vectors of length `nrow(mydata)`, I would suggest using `match` with matrix indexing.